# I want to Show arraylist values in jsp page using logic equals

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have created one ArrayList

```
private List<StatisticsDetails> qNamesList ;
```

`qNamesList` contains `StatisticsDetails` bean where it holds right now that is, MR-Not Reviewed=12. If multiple values there then I'm splitting based on symbol `^`. Here, MR-Not Reviewed=12^MR-Reviewd=32. qKey =MR-Not Reviewed  and qCount = 12.

Now I have to show qKey =MR-Not Reviewed and qCount = 12 in my jsp page. As I can see my values in statisticsDetails Bean inside qNamesList arraylist.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: where you are wring the your java code is it inside the servlet ? or any other framework like structs or spring please share the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<StatisticsDetails> statisticsDetailsList = new ArrayList<StatisticsDetails>();
        for (String queueName : qName) {
            StatisticsDetails details = new StatisticsDetails();
            String[] splitQueues = queueName.split("=");
            details.setqKey(splitQueues[0]);
            details.setqCount(splitQueues[1]);
            statisticsDetailsList.add(details);
        }
        statisticsDetails.setqNamesList(statisticsDetailsList);
        request.setAttribute("key",statisticsDetails);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("target.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

in jsp :

```
 StatisticsDetails sd = (StatisticsDetails) request.getAttribute("key");
 List<StatisticsDetails> list = sd.getQNamesList();
 use list in jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

incase if you are writing your code inside your servlet you can keep your lsit in

```
request.setAttribute("key",qNamesList);
then redirect to your jsp page using
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/target.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

once you navigate to jsp page use the bellow code in jsp

```
ArrayList al = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute();
```

then loop it to get the data how you want and one more thing import ArrayList using taglib directive tags

Comment: better to JSTL inside JSP

Comment: List<StatisticsDetails> statisticsDetailsList = new ArrayList<StatisticsDetails>();
for (String queueName: qName  ){
StatisticsDetails  details = new StatisticsDetails();
String[] splitQueues = queueName.split("=");

details.setqKey(splitQueues[0]);
details.setqCount(splitQueues[1]);
statisticsDetailsList.add(details);

}
statisticsDetails.setqNamesList(statisticsDetailsList); this way i'm looping

Comment: hay puja are you using struts or spring ?

Comment: struts  im using